# Why is the DataContext null in the Loaded Event?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, datacontext, activator

I am using Activator.Createinstance to create an object. There're two scenarios in which I create an object. One when the object is created in the default state without caring about functionality. Second when it has some properties/data to load, which I read from XML file.
I read an xml file and create a specific object based on the content in that file and then call a method of that object to load the properties. The problem occurs when the user control loads: The datacontext is null most of the times but not always. This doesn't happen when I create the object with no data to be loaded.

Following code initializes the object:

```
Type gadgetType = Type.GetType(ObName);
IControl ctrl = (IControl)Activator.CreateInstance(gadgetType);
```

This code executes in both scenarios. The only additional code which executes in second case is following.

```
ctrl.CreateFromXml(item);//item is xelement
```

and in Control the loaded event goes like this.

```
 void Control_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { ControlViewModel cvm = (ControlViewModel)this.DataContext; //DataContext is null }
```

Comment: Where is your `DataContext` set with `ControlViewModel` class ? In XAML ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I tried to set it in Code behind as well. but that too didnt fix it.

Comment: DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=ControlViewModel}" >

Comment: Are you sure your resource exists?  If you look in the debug window, you will see any errors that occurred during databinding; you might see what went wrong there.

Comment: Finally figure it out. It was wrong event handlers call. Thanks!

Comment: @user433023 care to share?? I'm running into this issue as well

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue, you can access the DataContext in code-behind on initialization by handling the DataContextChanged event instead of the Loaded event.  In my experience, the DataContext has usually been null in the Loaded event.

In the constructor:

```
DataContextChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(OnDataContextChanged);
```

Event handler:

```
private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // your data context won't be null here.  At least it 
    // wasn't for me.
    if (DataContext is not null)
    {
        // your stuff here
    }
}
```